# What does StackExchange.Redis do with the configured Masters/Slaves?

Tags: c#, stackexchange.redis

I'm looking at StackExchange.Redis and notice it has features for automatically determining which of the configured servers is master, and which are slaves.

I've not managed to spot what StackExchange actually *does* with the configured Masters/Slaves. Does it always run commands on Master, and only use configured Slaves for failover? Or is the answer more in-depth than that?

Any pointers appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key thing here is `CommandFlags`, a parameter on every method. By default, most are `PreferMaster`, however; note that write commands escalate to `DemandMaster` automatically. However, if you want to spread load, you can elect to push some read commands (preferably the expensive ones) to slaves via `PreferSlave` and `DemandSlave`.

The other things it lets you do is to switch master (promote to master) - although this is naturally more invasive.