# StackExchange.Redis using only master and ignore slave

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis

I am using StackExchange.Redis with master/slave.

I am reading  with `CommandFlags.PreferSlave`, but  when I am looking inside i see no use on the slave.
I want to use the slave for reads! the slave is connected but ignored. why?

```
redis1:6379: Standalone v3.0.3, master; 16 databases; keep-alive: 00:01:00; int: ConnectedEstablished; sub: ConnectedEstablished, 1 active 
redis1:6379: int ops=163768, qu=0, qs=0, qc=0, wr=0, sync=163766, async=2, socks=1; sub ops=47, qu=0, qs=0, qc=0, wr=0, subs=1, sync=47, socks=1 
Circular op-count snapshot; int: 162882+163+126+54+104+128+86+39+54+76+56=163768 (88.60 ops/s; spans 10s); sub: 47 (0.00 ops/s; spans 10s) 
redis2:6379: Standalone v3.0.3, slave; 16 databases; keep-alive: 00:01:00; int: ConnectedEstablished; sub: ConnectedEstablished, 1 active 
redis2:6379: int ops=56, qu=0, qs=0, qc=0, wr=0, sync=54, async=2, socks=1; sub ops=47, qu=0, qs=0, qc=0, wr=0, subs=1, sync=47, socks=1 
Circular op-count snapshot; int: 56 (0.00 ops/s; spans 10s); sub: 47 (0.00 ops/s; spans 10s) 
Sync timeouts: 0; fire and forget: 0; last heartbeat: 0s ago
```

Comment: [Might be related](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30603886/859154) , but have you tried "DemandSlave" ?

Comment: I don't want to use only slave, as I need redundancy.